# iText - TU Entries in PDF Dictionary

Tags: pdf, dictionary

I have the following code in Java. How can I create a PDF Dictionary and add TU entries to it? I have an instance of PdFReader, Acrofields, and PdfStamper. It is currently printing out the field names. I'm trying to add TU entries so that I can change the field names.

```
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import java.util.Set;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class PDFFile {


public static final String xfaForm3 = "C:/PDF_Service/pdf-project/src/sample.pdf";
public static final String dest = "sample2.xml";

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

PdfReader reader; 
PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
AcroFields form;

try{

   reader = new PdfReader(xfaForm3);
   PdfStamper stamper2 = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
   form = stamper2.getAcroFields();
   stamper2.close();
   Set<String> fldNames = form.getFields().keySet();


  for (String fldName : fldNames) 

  {

    System.out.println( fldName +  " : " + form.getField( fldName ) );

   }


  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();

   }    
  }
```